# Using 3D matrices to transform 2D points with constraints

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am working on a program that require to transform the plane according to a matrix. Although I am working on a 2D plane I am using 3D matrices, so that it can encorperate translation as well. All points on the plane have their normal x and y coordinates, along with a z coordinate of 1. When I say "the plane" I mean the plane $z=1$.

This matrix in question is of the following form:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & c & e \\
    b & d & f \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

The constraints mentioned in the title are that there are two points, $A$ and $B$, that need to move to $A'$ and $B'$ respectively. I also want this transformation to not skew the plane, preserving the shape of objects on it, and just translate, rotate, and scale it.

I have managed to reduce it to two unknowns and fix the points, but I don't know how to fix the skew and remove the other unknowns. I have calculated
$$c=\frac{B'_x-A'_x-aB_x+aA_x}{B_y-A_y}$$
$$d=\frac{B'_y-A'_y-bB_x+bA_x}{B_y-A_y}$$
$$e=A'_x-(aA_x+cA_y)$$
$$f=A'_y-(bA_x+dA_y)$$

Comment: You have 4 parameters: 1 for the scaling factor, 1 for the angle of the rotation (since the rotation axis is the $z$ axis) and 2 for the translation. The mapping of a point into another one gives 2 conditions. You have 2 such mappings to do, so you have a total of 4 conditions. You should be able to set all the values. I guess that you are not familiar with rotation matrices (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Can you guess what are additional conditions on your values $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$? Side note: I didn't check your equations.